# Angular routing just appending to url not going to new page

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-routing

I am just trying to link when I click on an object in my home component that it brings me to the player detail component. I send in the method with all the data is sent correctly but it just appends to the url instead of actually going to the new page itself.

I also don't know where I should put the  because it ends up constantly trying to render the player detail page if I have it in any component.

app-routing.module

```
import { NgModule } from "@angular/core";
import { Routes, RouterModule } from "@angular/router";
import { PlayerDetailComponent } from "./components/player-detail/player-detail.component";

const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: "details/:playerID/:firstName/:lastName/:teamID",
    component: PlayerDetailComponent
  }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule {}
```

my home.component.ts

```
showDetails(
    playerID: String,
    firstName: String,
    lastName: String,
    teamID: String
  ) {
    this.router.navigate(["/details", playerID, firstName, lastName, teamID]);
  }
```

`EDIT`

I changed the app-routing to this

```
import { NgModule } from "@angular/core";
import { Routes, RouterModule } from "@angular/router";
import { HomeComponent } from "./components/home/home.component";
import { PlayerDetailComponent } from "./components/player-detail/player-detail.component";

const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: "",
    component: HomeComponent
  },
  {
    path: "details/:playerID/:firstName/:lastName/:teamID",
    component: PlayerDetailComponent
  }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule {}
```

And my app component html is just this

```
<div class="main-container">
  <div>
    <router-outlet></router-outlet>
  </div>
</div>
```

This works but I really don't get why and what if I wanted to add a button back to the home page how would I do that now?

`EDIT 2`

I realized I just have to do '' if I want to go back to the home page.

Comment: Post a complete minimal example as a stackblitz. My guess is that you don't have a router-outlet in your template.

Comment: i put a router outlet in the app.component.html it just puts the player detail component of top of the home one and if I put the router outlet in my player detail it still does the same thing

Comment: app.component.html is **always** displayed. If you want some part of this template to only be displayed in the home page, then that part should be in a separate home component, and the home component should be the component of the home route, mapped to the empty path.

Comment: You would use `<a routerLink="/">Home</a>`. Have you read the angular.io guide about routing?

Comment: I did I was just confused with where the router-outlet is supposed to go

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You generally have some type of navigation outside the `router-outlet` to navigate to different components.  All you components will render in the `router-outlet` and you can use the navigation to navigate to different features.

Also you may not want to pass all your player details with path params but instead use a shared/central service to store your data and let your components access that data through the service.  An example is when you go to player details, just use the player `id` as a path param then pull that players details from the central service.

I put together an stackblitz example of a possible structure for the application.

> https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-wm6pdm

Comment: That definitely helped clear up some confusion thank you.

Comment: @joe_monaco98 Not a problem.  If you have any questions let me know.